# In Gnome + wayland is it possible to paste primary selection with a keyboard that doesn't have an insert key?

Tags: keyboard, gnome, wayland

I use gnome with wayland and I don't have an insert key on my laptop. Is there any way to paste the primary selection without using an insert key from the keyboard? I don't like having to reach for the mouse to click the middle mouse button.

I was thinking about using hwdb for this but it doesn't support key-chords and I can't figure out how to make it the weird special keys I don't normally use, such as "KEY_SEARCH", to the insert key.

Is there a solution using hwdb or any other method?